# what if my network like tcp and icmp headers sizes are not multiple of 2 bytes(16 bits)then if I have one end byte how to do checksum on this one byte

Tags: c, networking, tcp, icmp

So my icmp header is 9 byte long along with ping data. I used a algorithm like following to calculate checksum, but its not working

```
int calculate_checksum(void *vdata,size_t size)
{
    uint16_t *ptr = vdata;
    int i = 0;
    uint16_t sum = -0xffff;

    printf("size = %zu\n",size);

    while(i < (size/2))
    {
                        
        //printf("%d = %x \n",i,*(ptr + i));
        sum += ntohs(*(ptr+i));
        printf("%x %x\n",ntohs(*(ptr+i)),sum);
        if(sum > 0xffff)
        {
            sum -=0xffff;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    
            
    
    printf("checksum = %x\n", ~sum&0x0000FFFF);
    sum = ~sum;
    return htons(sum);
    

}
```

problem it looks to be my 9th byte is not being included. but its just one byte with hex value of 0x63 so to make 16 bit number so what do I need to do. Is there a way or solution for this?

what I know calcusum is doing sum on each 16 bits of headers

Comment: The TCP, ICMP, etc. headers are *specified* to follow a specific format. You can't change the header format, or their sizes. The specifications also contains texts on how to handle extra data *added* after the standard headers, and how to handle padding etc. You might want to take a closer look at the relevant RFC's to see what they say.

Comment: As for the checksum calculation, there must be thousand of tutorials and examples on how to calculate that. If you look around at existing solutions, how do they handle situations like this (if they ever arise)?

Comment: There is even C code provided in an [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1071).

Comment: @user207421 ok I fixed my algorithm. But now wireshark tagging my icmp ping request as `no response data`. Any idea do u have please tell. I have 8 byte data all `a`s